# Javascript Scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

On some blogs, when you scroll towards the bottom of the page they will have a DIV that slides into view in the bottom right corner of the page.

A lot of times on a blog article, onces you get down the page to about the point where the Comment section starts is where they will have this DIV slide into view.

I am trying to replicate this, I saw one site that does it but it doesn't do it near the comments instead it uses this code below which you can see is around the half way point.

`Document height - the Window height / 2`

So it's actually left then half way down the page.  How would I go about having it come into view when I get to the comment section of the page, let's say my comments are wrapped in a DIV with the ID `comments`

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var curPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    var docHeight = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
    if (curPos > (docHeight / 2)) {
      MoneyBox.show();
    } else {
      MoneyBox.hide();
    }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try comparing the scrollTop and the offset of your div

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    var curPos = $(document).scrollTop();

    var commentsPos = $('#comments').offset().top;

    if(curPos >= commentsPos) {
        MoneyBox.show();
    } else {
        MoneyBox.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I thought of that right after I posted but then I wasn't sure how to get the offset of the DIV so thanks!  Ill accept this once it lets me

Comment: Final result I took `$('#comments').offset().top` and subtract `$(window).height()` to form my `commentsPos` so that I can fire my action as soon as the `#comment` comes into view